# Find Value at a given Orientation in Matrix

Tags: matlab, image-processing, matrix

In **Matlab** I've matrix where, in a previous stage of my code, an specific element was chosen. From this point of the matrix I would like to find a maximum, not just the maximum value between all its surounding neighbours for a given radius, but the **maximum value at a given angle of orientation**. Let me explain this with an example:

This is matrix A:

A =

```
 0     1     1     1     0     0     9     1     0     
 0     2     2     4     3     2     8     1     0     
 0     2     2     3     3     2     2     1     0     
 0     1     1     3     2     2     2     1     0     
 0     8     2     3     3     2     7     2     1    
 0     1     1     2     3     2     3     2     1
```

The element chosen in the first stage is the **4** in A(2,4), and the next element should be the maximum value with, for example, a 315 degrees angle of orientation, that is the **7** in A(5,7).

What I've done is, depending on the angle, subdivide matrix A in different quadrants and make a new matrix (an A's submatrix) with only the values of that quadrant.

So, for this example, the **submatrix** will be A's 4th quadrant:

q_A =

```
 4     3     2     8     1     0     
 3     3     2     2     1     0     
 3     2     2     2     1     0     
 3     3     2     7     2     1     
 2     3     2     3     2     1
```

And now, here is my question, how can I extract the **7**?

The only thing I've been able to do (and it works) is to find all the values over a threshold value and then calculate how those points are orientated. Then, saving all the values that have a similar orientation to the given one (315 degrees in this example) and finally finding the maximum among them. It works but I guess there could be a much faster and "cleaner" solution.

Comment: Have you tried `imrotate` using nearest neighbour interpolation to and your element (r,c) as the center to make your angle always be 0? Then it's just `max(Arotated(r,c:end))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my theory, but I don't have the image processing toolbox to test it. Maybe someone who does can comment?

```
%make (r,c) the center by padding with zeros
    if r > size(A,1)/2
        At = padarray(A, [size(A,1) - r], 0, 'pre');
    else
        At = padarray(A, [r-1], 0 'post');

    if c > size(A,2)/2
        At = padarray(At, [size(A,2) - c], 0, 'pre');
    else
        At = padarray(At, [c-1], 0 'post');

%rotate by your angle (maybe this should be -angle or else 360-angle or 2*pi-angle, I'm not sure
    Ar = imrotate(At,angle, 'nearest', 'loose'); %though I think nearest and loose are defaults

%find the max

    max(Ar(size(Ar,1)/2, size(Ar,2)/2:end); %Obviously you must adjust this to handle the case of odd dimension sizes.
```

Also depending on your array requirements, padding with `-inf` might be better than `0`

Comment: Rotating... sounds good! I'll try it. But, my problem is that, the value I'm looking for should be around the given angle. Maybe, by doing what you propose with a couple of angles above & below the given one could work. Thank you!

Comment: @karl71 But like I said, I don't have the toolbox to test any of that so I suggest you run each line and check the output to make sure it makes sense. Especially because it could easily be one row/column off etc.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a relatively inexpensive solution to the problem, although I found wrapping my head around the matrix coordinate system a real pain, and there is probably room to tidy it up somewhat. It simply traces all matrix entries along a line around the starting point at the supplied angle (all coordinates and angles are of course based on matrix index units):

```
A = [ 0     1     1     1     0     0     9     1     0
      0     2     2     4     3     2     8     1     0
      0     2     2     3     3     2     2     1     0
      0     1     1     3     2     2     2     1     0
      0     8     2     3     3     2     7     2     1
      0     1     1     2     3     2     3     2     1 ];
alph = 315;
r = 2;
c = 4;
% generate a line through point (r,c) with angle alph
[nr nc] = size(A);
x = [1:0.1:nc]; % overkill
m = tan(alph);
b = r-m*c;
y = m*x + b;
crd = unique(round([y(:) x(:)]),'rows');
iok = find((crd(:,1)>0) & (crd(:,1)<=nr) & (crd(:,2)>0) & (crd(:,2)<=nc));
crd = crd(iok,:);
indx=sub2ind([nr,nc],crd(:,1),crd(:,2));
% find max and position of max
[val iv]=max(A(indx)); % <-- val is the value of the max
crd(iv,:)             % <-- matrix coordinates (row, column) of max value
```

Result:

```
val =

     7


iv =

     8


ans =

     5     7
```